Error starting the second domain in GlassFish
I'm facing a problem when trying to run a second domain on the GlassFish server, each configured on different ports. When accessing the /__asadmin/version route on the second domain, an "Internal Server Error" error occurs. The exception is a java.lang.RuntimeException followed by a java.io.IOException indicating that the connection has been closed. Here is the relevant stack trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:265)at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:420) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:613) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.write(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:60) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
